# csrf token value did not set automatically

Tags: angular, csrf

I need to send csrf token to the request header. currently token value come like below
[image]

I did angular configurations in 'app.module.ts'
`  imports: [

```
  CommonModule,
  BrowserModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
    cookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    headerName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
  }),
  NgSelectModule,
  NgIdleKeepaliveModule,
  TranslateModule.forRoot({
    loader: {
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
      deps: [HttpClient]
    }
  }),
  AppRoutingModule
```

],`

but when i check my request header. cookie did not set automatically. but angular document said, it happen automatically. what is the issue in my side

how to set response cookie and send it in request header

Answer (score 0):

By default, an interceptor sends this header on all mutating requests (such as POST) to relative URLs, but not on GET/HEAD requests or on requests with an absolute URL.

Comment: is this wrong approach ?

Comment: No, this is from the official doc.  You have to read it more carefully.https://angular.io/guide/http-security-xsrf-protection